# What ROR plugins or projects offer account creation with built-in admin account access levels and pre-built views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm working on a project that will involve creating a subdomain for each client's projects.  Admin-level users will be able to create project-area subdomains. Admins will also be able to create and delete standard users.

I'm trying to figure out what tools, or projects I can utilise to get as much of this out of the box as possible. Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at Rails 3.1 (rc). It handles subdomains better. No need for plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need [subdomain_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu) to handle the subdomains and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.

Comment: Have you used devise? How well would it handle the admin and user creation scenarios out of the box?  Is a superadmin (for creating admins) easy with devise as well?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward and fairly full featured as far as access systems go. Best way to find out if it fits your needs is to try it for yourself.